# reduce size of apk using HoloEveryWhere

Tags: android-widget, apk, android-holo-everywhere

I am using HoloEveryWhere in my project. But i am not happy with the size of the final apk. **Can anyone provide specific guidelines on how to reduce size or include only specific styles that would be effective application wide.**

P.S. Spinners are not looking as they should be. Is there anything special to do for spiiners to make use of holoeverywhere styles.

Answer (score 0):

Since Proguard does not reduce size of library projects you can't signifcantly reduse total size of your apk. You can delete unused resources such as dark theme, if you using only light one, but it will save only about 300-400 kB.

Comment: P.S. there is a tool called DexGuard, may be it can help, but it cost 350 € for individual developer. I don't have licence, and I can't tell how usefull it is.